# why difference between this example and matlab result

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design, infinite-impulse-response

everyone

fs=30 000 , fc=3000;

[image]

when i code apply this in matlab result is very difference

```
[b,a]=butter(2,3000/30000,'low');
b=[0.020083365564211 0.040166731128423 0.020083365564211],
a=[1 -1.561018075800718 0.641351538057563]
```

but when i suddenly remember in matlab use nyquist sampling so , when i do apply fs/2 , result is still difference

```
[b,a]=butter(2,3000/15000,'low');
b=[0.067455273889072 0.134910547778144 0.067455273889072]
a=[1 -1.142980502539901 0.412801598096189]
```

thank you for helping sorry my bad language

Comment: From which book is the scan?

Comment: Digital Filter Designer's Handbook 
C.Britton Rorabaugh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Matlab's function `butter`, all frequencies need to be normalized by $f_s/2$, so your second call to the function `butter` is the correct one, the first one is wrong. And, as usually, Matlab is correct. The difference between the solution in your book and Matlab's solution is that the function `butter` uses prewarping to guarantee that after the bilinear transformation, the resulting cut-off frequency of the digital filters equals the specified cut-off frequency. For whatever reason, the solution in your book doesn't take the frequency warping of the bilinear transform into account, so the resulting cut-off frequency of the digital filter does *not* exactly equal the desired $\omega_c$.

The frequency warping caused by the bilinear transform used in your book maps the cut-off frequency $\omega_c$ of the analog filter to the following cut-off frequency of the resulting digital filter:

$$\tilde{\omega}_c=\frac{2}{T}\arctan\left(\frac{\omega_cT}{2}\right)=2\pi\cdot 2906.8\tag{1}$$

instead of $\omega_c=2\pi\cdot 3000$.

You can check the actual cut-off frequencies of the digital filters using the following Matlab commands:

```
wc = pi/5;                          % normalized cut-off frequency
wc2 = 2*atan((2*pi*3000)/30000/2);  % normalized warped cut-off frequency
[b,a] = butter(2,wc/pi,'low');      % Matlab's solution
b0 = 0.063964*[1,2,1];              % solution from book
a0 = [1,-1.168261,0.424118]
abs(freqz(b,a,[0,wc])).^2           % check |H|^2 at DC and at wc;
                                    % (should be [1,0.5])
abs(freqz(b0,a0,[0,wc])).^2         % [0.99999   0.46637]
abs(freqz(b0,a0,[0,wc2])).^2        % [0.99999   0.49999]
```

This shows that the filter in the book indeed has cut-off frequency $\tilde{\omega}_c$ given in $(1)$ instead of $\omega_c$.

If you don't understand the frequency warping of the bilinear transform, I'd suggest you study chapter 11 of [this excellent and free book](http://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~orfanidi/intro2sp/orfanidis-i2sp.pdf) by S.J. Orfanidis.